Do I need to use Git env vars when I'm using Docker Portainer env vars?
Do I need to pass/load env vars from let's say Bitbucket into my docker environment which uses Portainer or it's common practice and enough to control these env vars via Portainer UI by adding env vars into stacks? Like Stripe publishable key or other API keys or so on?
